# Objective-C: Making an NSArray from an NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsarray

I'm trying to make an array from file path components. I have an array of file paths (as NSStrings) and I am looping through them, then breaking each down like so:

```
//get the array of image paths
imageList = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"images"];

//loop through the array and get the image names
for (NSString* thisImagePath in imageList) {
    NSArray* thisImagePathArray = [thisImagePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
```

Half the time my program is crashing here. I get the following error message:

```
-[NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a7940
```

imageList is an array of files dropped onto a view. Because this problem started popping up I am only dropping one file at a time. For example:

This file did not work:

```
/Users/steve/Desktop/thinkstock/PT121211_PI_bariatric.tif
```

This did

```
/Users/steve/Desktop/thinkstock/Studentexhausted82557038.jpg
```

so, if I understand the error message correctly I am trying to apply the componentsSeparatedByString selector to an NSArray, which doesn't support that selector. But in my loop I am calling for NSString, if the object was an array shouldn't I crash there? (And I am 99% sure the object at index 0 of imageList is a string.)

My objective is to get the file name from the file path, is there a better way of doing it than the approach I am taking?

When I step through (putting a debug point at the componentsSeparatedByString line it seems to work as I planned:

[image]

But if I hit continue it crashes.

As suggested I changed my code to log data:

```
//loop through the array and get the image names
for (NSString* thisImagePath in imageList) {
if (![thisImagePath isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { 
    NSLog(@"The class of this object is: %@", [thisImagePath className]);
}
NSLog(@"%@", thisImagePath); 

NSArray* thisImagePathArray = [thisImagePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString* thisImageName = [thisImagePathArray objectAtIndex:[thisImagePathArray count]-1];
```

The conditional for the class check never get triggered, as everything is of NSString class. However, some files work, some don't...

```
2012-01-19 13:59:04.631 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] /Users/steve/Desktop/thinkstock/rbrb_0556.jpg
2012-01-19 13:59:06.799 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] /Users/steve/Desktop/thinkstock/Manracefinish78464007.jpg
2012-01-19 13:59:08.319 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] /Users/steve/Desktop/thinkstock/ManLabtop86510699.jpg
2012-01-19 13:59:08.320 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] *** -[NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a75c0
2012-01-19 13:59:08.321 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] *** Canceling drag because exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' (reason '*** -[NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a75c0') was raised during a dragging session
2012-01-19 13:59:10.726 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] /Users/steve/Desktop/thinkstock/LasVegassign78058995.jpg
2012-01-19 13:59:10.728 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] *** -[NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a9010
2012-01-19 13:59:10.729 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] *** Canceling drag because exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' (reason '*** -[NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a9010') was raised during a dragging session
2012-01-19 13:59:13.342 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] /Users/steve/Desktop/thinkstock/kidscolor57448860.jpg
2012-01-19 13:59:15.014 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] /Users/steve/Desktop/thinkstock/IVDrip76801701.jpg
2012-01-19 13:59:18.263 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] /Users/steve/Desktop/thinkstock/stk26719pin.jpg
2012-01-19 13:59:23.414 archiveDrop_cocoa[76758:10b] /Users/steve/Desktop/thinkstock/WomanLabtop78634274.jpg
```

Comment: When you break in the debugger on the line where you call `componentsSeparatedByString:`, what does the debugger say `thisImagePath` is?

Comment: Hint:  NSLog thisImagePath before you attempt to apply componentsSeparatedByString to it.

Comment: @HotLicks - I have, those two paths I posted came directly from the log.

Comment: @user118321 - NSCFString* thisImagePath 0x8b1840

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're 100% sure that you really get a NSString here, why don't you use `[thisImagePath lastPathComponent]`?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lastPathComponent

Comment: You get the win for turning me on to the lastPathComponent...thanks that helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

One of the entries in your image list is an NSArray.  You need to figure out why that is.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at `NSString's -lastPathComponent` or `-pathComponents` instead of calling `-componentsSeparatedByString:` since they will parse paths reliably.

Like Hot Licks suggested, it looks like you are trying to call `-componentsSeparatedByString` on an `NSArray`. I would `NSLog( @"imageList: %@", imageList )` for a few sample file drops and look at what you are getting, or possibly inside the for loop

```
if ( ![thisImagePath isKindOfClass:[NSString class] ) NSLog( @"Not a String: %@", thisImagePath );
```

Comment: See edits above, thanks for the isKindOfClass push, that cleared up that at least I am getting strings in my loop. Now to figure out why the app thinks some of those strings are arrays in the next line of code...

Comment: Problem solved - it's happening further down the line, where I am pulling the metadata from the file, specifically the keywords. These are stock photos and not abiding by any standardization, some have keywords as strings, some have them as arrays. Voted everyone up for the help.